# Xamarin IOS Shell Itemtemplate FlyoutIcon FontAwesome

Tags: ios, shell, xamarin

I have an Xamarin Shell App.  I pulled the code straight from MSDN for the Shell Itemtemplate and it works fine an Android but on IOS the FlyoutIcon is not appearing.  I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that I am using FontAwesome for Icons.  However I have yet to run across any documentation explaining why there would be an issue with IOS.  The icons work perfectly everywehre else in the app.  Below is the code for the shell item

```
 <!-- ItemTemplate is for ShellItems as displayed in a Flyout-->
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentView BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.2*,0.8*" Margin="10">
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}" 
                   Margin="5"
                   HeightRequest="20" />

                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Title}" 
                   TextColor="LightSlateGray"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ContentView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Could you provide the font file and other relavant code(viewmodel) to help us to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Are you making sure that FlyoutIcon image exist in the ios image resources?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT after more sleuthing I found the issue is that on IOS when you set the phones theme to LIght, it turns the FlyoutIcons Black in the Shell Item Template.
I found someone with the same issue where I too submitted the bug
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11406
You can see my .xaml format there.  
Currently there does not seem to be a way to fix this......

Comment: This is a design issue ,you can continue to use the workaround you provided ,and wait for the fix by xamairn developing team .